# Can't load MySQL 5.5.40 data files with MySQL 5.5.50

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, debian, backup

Background:
My server didn't work anymore after an "apt-get upgrade".. my provider told me that they don't support Ubuntu 12 any more and that I should get a fresh install.. I couldn't export the MySQL tables since mysql didn't work any more (which is the reason for the fresh install).

The Situation:
Now I have a fresh Debian 8 server with MySQL 5.5.50 and my datafiles which were created by MySQL 5.5.40. I tried to change my.cnf to set the data dir to my backup - but mysql wouldn't start with this configuration.

The Question: 
Should what i try work?
What am I doing wrong?
How do i find out more about the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: DBAs would be in a lot better position to answer this question than sw developers.

Comment: You can find out more about the problem in the error messages that are displayed or logged when you try to start your server. What should work: Copy your backup (I assume you mean: you saved the complete hdd content of your old system that you made before debian 8 installation, but with a non-running mysql server) to the existing new data directory according to your new `my.cfg`, replacing everything (after you did a backup of your new system). That should take care of most possible problems (assuming your backup is not corrupt). You might have missed some permissions.